# FPC for Survey design in Brazilian Demographic Census 2010

Tags: r, survey, census

So, I need to analyze  data about Brazilian Censo 2010 using R, and I'm having troubles to use the survey package.

At ASDF, you may see how Brazilian Censo data works: http://asdfree.com/brazilian-censo-demografico-censo.html

But, there is this problem: I don't know what fpc I need to set. At ADSF they kind of tried to create this variable using lodown and other functions, but when I try to replicate them, the downloaded always come incomplete for some reason. Actually, it does not go to the defined output folder, and in the temporary folder the files are minuscule (like 2KB).

I am able to collect the data from another sources, but in this case the problem is that I don't know which FPC I have to set in the survey design.

Can someone help me with this?

I am not including any code because it is in the link I provided above.

Kind regards!

Comment: You'll have to be more specific with your problem. But note that the `fpc` argument is optional in all of the survey design functions. If not supplied, then finite population correction is not applied when calculating standard errors. It's not usually an issue unless the proportion of the sample is more than ~10% of the population.

Comment: Is this a programming question or a statistics question? If you are asking purely  about setting FPC might this question be better moved to Cross Validated as "How to set FPC...?"

Comment: @Edward, it is exactly 10% of the population.

Comment: @Peter, I am not sure. I need to figure out how to use survey design functions in R. Since I am using it with a specific data base, I was hoping that - if FPC is indeed required - someone could help me manually calculate it using R functions as well. Maybe creating a new variable that might result in the correct FPC.

Comment: I am going to use R a lot from now on, not only in this paper. So this is also a sort of check on how the R communities across the web is willing to help, HOW should I ask for help, etc.

Comment: In the survey package, the `fpc` is the variable that refers to the population sizes _or_ the fraction of the population sampled at each stage. If you don't have this information, then omit it. The command will still work. However you'll need to supply the sampling weights (or probabilities), otherwise R will assume equal weights, which is usually not appropriate for large-scale or national surveys.

Comment: SO is a site for asking coding-related questions. You haven't provided any code or any data. And pasting links to external sites is discouraged.

Comment: Maybe spend a bit of time looking at these links (if you have not already done so!): [ask] and [reprex].

Comment: could you pinpoint the issue inside of this function?  https://github.com/ajdamico/lodown/blob/master/R/censo.R   maybe send a pull request if something is behaving incorrectly